# Update: Did the U.S. Government shut down take US Census API offline?

Tags: data.gov

Did the US Census API just now go offline because of government shutdown? https://api.census.gov was working as recently as 4-5 am this morning. But now its not working (at least for me).

UPDATE: So I discovered that you can't access the year "2017" for the ACS, which was possible yesterday. But you can access 2016 and 2015.

Example: https://api.census.gov/data/2017/acs/acs5/subject?get=  will fail

https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5/subject?get= will work

Is this normal for how they update the data? I figured they wouldn't be updating the site since the gov shut down (and they say so on the website).

Comment: give full examples of failing/passing API calls, minus your API key please

Comment: Either way they may take it offline or not updating anything until the Government returns from the shutdown. if you try email or call them , they will not answer anything ...

Comment: Now the API for the 2017 ACS is working again. That was strange. A full example would be https://api.census.gov/data/2017/acs/acs5/subject?get=S2503_C02_013E&for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:20005 wasn't working this morning, but is working now. But I'm not sure how as there should be nobody there working to fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can no longer be reproduced